# Как найти и заменить текст в файле через регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как найти и заменить текст в файле через регулярное выражение в js?

**Условия поиска**:

**1.** Совпадение из девяти любых цифр подряд.

**2.** Совпадение текста - "mytext", который сразу идет после девяти цифр.

**3.** Если такое совпадение есть, заменяем его на "123412341www"

**4.** Глобальный поиск

Comment: https://ideone.com/IOjdNI

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский - спасибо. Но это в Php.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский нужен доступ к js переменным.

Comment: че-то я на автопилоте)) помню что у вас вопрос были про `yii2` вот и написал

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Но все равно спасибо, это тоже нужная информация. Если вы напишите в ответе как вариант, я поставлю плюсик .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам подойдёт следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/\d{9}mytext/g
```

Пример использования:

```
var s = "123456789mytext23424kjfjhkjdhfgkj123456789mytext nmfdfmng";
s = s.replace(/\d{9}mytext/g, "123412341www");
```

---

Если нужно, чтобы вместо фиксированного текста `mytext` в регулярном выражении находился текст из переменной, придётся несколько усложнить код и использовать объект `RegExp`:

```
var myText = "mytext";
var s = "123456789mytext23424kjfjhkjdhfgkj123456789mytext nmfdfmng";
var re = new RegExp("\\d{9}" + myText, "g");
s = s.replace(re, "123412341www");
```

Comment: kff Скажите а как вставить сюда переменную `mytext `?

Comment: Кукую переменную? Куда "сюда"? Уточните.

Comment: вот сюда - `mytext` Я просто случайно нажал отправить не успев дописать.

Comment: что бы было вроде того  `var mytext = "testr";  s = s.replace(/\d{9}mytext/g, "123412341www");`

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за полный и качественный ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Рад был помочь! :-)